# Greyhound Canada - How do I book bus tickets online for passengers with multiple discounts?

Tags: online-resources, canada, buses, greyhound

I want to buy bus tickets for a trip on [Greyhound](http://www.greyhound.ca) for multiple passengers. One passenger has a student card and the other has a Hostelling International card. They have different pricing conditions on Greyhound, one has about 10% off, the other 25% off if I remember that well.

When booking online, there is only one drop-down for the discount to apply, no matter how many passengers are travelling, which implies all passengers are entitled to the same discount.

I was thinking about buying the tickets separately, but several things make it impossible or annoying:

- The traveller should be the cardholder
- My bank charges a fee per transaction (as my account is not in CAD)

The rules sound pretty strict overall, but I have no idea how enforced these are when getting on the bus.

Can I book bus tickets for several passengers with different discounts and still get all the discounts applied properly?

Comment: You likely need to call and book with a human.  Their online system doesn't seem set up for your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the online site doens't have all the features that a phone booking or in-person booking does.  Perhaps one day.  It's not however, a duplicate of their functionality.

Most common bookings can indeed be done online, and the assumption is travellers likely have similar discounts, if any.

You have two options:

1. Book two separate transactions, which gets you the discount, but causes you problems with bank fees and cardholder rights.  You can also get the web discount, which is sometimes cheaper than in person anyway.
2. Phone or book in person (if possible).  This allows more complex bookings, and should let you do it in one transaction.

Comment: for the item 2., the main advantage of online booking is there is a web discount, and the web discount with no other discount is often more interesting than the other discount at the station counter. For my case, I ended up buying with two separate transactions as it was still cheaper than at the station.

Comment: Valid point, I'll add that in.